# How To Use Django-Crontab in Ec2 ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2

cronjob

```
*/30 * * * * /home/ubuntu/web-coin-crawler/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/web-coin-crawler/webcoincrawler/cron.crontab
```

cron.py, crontab() Function that crawls on two sites. Save to Django orm as save().

```
import json
import collections

import crawl_coinmarketcal as coinmarketcal
import crawl_coinscalendar as coinscalendar
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
import django
import datetime

django.setup()
from crawled_data.models import BlogData


def preprocessingDict(dic: dict):
    coin_dict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if value['symbol'] in coin_dict[value['date']]:
            coin_dict[value['date']][value['symbol']].append([key, value['title'], value['name']])
        else:
            coin_dict[value['date']][value['symbol']] = [[key, value['title'], value['name']]]
    return coin_dict


def crontab():
    result = dict()

    urls = coinmarketcal.get_urls()
    for url in urls:
        coinmarketcal.do_crawl(url, result)

    urls = coinscalendar.get_urls()
    for url in urls:
        coinscalendar.do_crawl(url, result)

    BlogData(title="COIN_DATA", content=json.dumps(preprocessingDict(result.copy()))).save()
```

[I checked that the cron tab runs every 30 minutes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jYS5.png)
However, no data was stored in Django orm.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Python file itself to run and it was solved.
cron.crontab -> cron